# Java storing in servlet context vs. database lookup

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, arraylist, dictionary

We are building a custom CMS in Java.

When the main servlet receives a request we perform a lookup to see which entry is associated with the request path and then display the entry to the user.

We are wondering which one of these 3 approaches is likely to be the fastest / cheapest in terms of performance:

1. storing a map of all entries in the servlet context at startup (key
   = path, value = entry) and then simply get the entry based on the path when a request is received
2. storing an array list of all entries in the servlet context at startup and then simply iterate on the list to get the entry based on the path when a request is received
3. performing a DB lookup to get the entry

To give you a bit more context, we currently have around 100 entries and expect this to grow to around 1,000. 
The DB is shared with a web application and we want to ensure maximum availability for the web app. At the same time SEO is our #1 source of traffic so maintaining a fast load time is extremely important for us.

Any thoughts on that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your DB, whatever it is, should be fast enough, especially to handle such a tiny amount of data. Caching it in memory won't bring any significant performance gain, but will make your app much more complex: when to invalidate the cache? How to be aware that something has been changed in the DB, and avoid displaying stale data? Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 0):

An in memory lookup will always be faster than a DB lookup. If the size of the data is not big and if the data does not change after loading, it would be a good option to store it in a Map (Iterating on a list would be a bad idea). If your server has memory to spare, then having a few MB's of data in memory will not be a problem.